# What is the umbrella term for being bilingual or monolingual?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I want to statistically analyse data which includes bilinguals and monolinguals. Being bilingual or monolingual are my independent variables. To analyse I need to write a column referring to bilinguals and monolinguals. For example column name "age" for participants who are 15 or 17.

Example sentence:

> The variable that indicates whether a person is fluent in one or two languages is called ...

Comment: Mono-and bilingual.

Comment: Languages. One or two. What happens to multi-linguals?

Comment: I just wanted to know that categorical name of being monolingual, bilingual or multilingual. Actually, does not matter how many language they know. For examle we have 5 participants and let's say their ages 5,6,7,8,9. When I put their ages into excel cells, I called this column as an age. So, I wonder how can I called the column which includes bilingual,monolingual or multilingual.

Comment: NumLanguages.   LangsKnown.  Or as Xanne says, just “Languages”

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELU is not a source for helping to name database fields or tables or programming language variable names.